# Artifactory upgrade from 6.4.1 to 7.x version

Tags: linux, upgrade, artifactory, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to upgrade Jfrog artifactory from 6.4.1 version to the latest 7.x version.
I'm not able to find the upgrade path in the [manual](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory).

Is there an official document on the upgrade path for the same?

Comment: Here is the doc - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554982/artifactory-upgrade-from-6-4-1-to-7-x-version. To upgrade from a version below 6.10.x, you first need to upgrade to version 6.10.x (or any 6.x version above 6.10.x) as described in the Upgrading Artifactory 6.x documentation, and then continue to upgrading from version 6.10 to 7.x.

Comment: The document link seems to be of the same question. Can you please share the correct document? If the document is right, then this should solve my issue.

Comment: link - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory

Answer (score 0):

The document that you referred is the correct document for the upgrade process.
I belive you are referring to Artifactory installed path. If yes, the default path would be /opt/jfrog/artifactory/. If it is zip installation in linux, there is a possibility that you might have installed in your own path. You can find the path below command in linux.

```
ps -ef | grep artifactory
```

If it is windows, you can open services and get the installed path of Artifactory. Later perform an upgrade.
Please be informed, that first you need to upgrade from 6.4.1 to 6.10 as there are some breaking changes. Later you can perform an upgrade to 7.x version. Depending on the installation type, you can follow the upgrade steps mentioned in the same document.

Comment: I'm not referring to the artifactory installation path. I'm referring to the upgrade path, i.e, the versions that I need to upgrade to before reaching the final version.

Comment: Then you have the answer already.
6.4.1 > 6.10 | 
6.10 > 7.x (any version of 7)

Answer (score 0):

For version below 6.10.x, first upgrade to 6.10.x and then upgrade to the version that is mentioned in the upgrade document.